# Как создать Button, чтобы скрыть/показать ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Как сделать кнопку при помощи которой можно скрыть/показать `ListView`

**UPD_0:**

```java
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData_proversebya_animal);
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProversebyaAnimal.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output));
        btn2.setText("Скрыть ошибки");

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData_proversebya_animal);
                listview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProversebyaAnimal.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output));
                btn2.setText("Показать ошибки");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Пример кода:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    Button btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData_proversebya_animal);
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProversebyaAnimal.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output));
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            boolean isShown = listview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
            listview.setVisibility(isShown ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
            btn2.setText(isShown ? R.string.hide_errors : R.string.show_errors);
        });
    }
}
```

Совет: используйте как можно меньше вызовов `findViewById` - это достаточно накладная операция (результат лучше сохранить в переменную и обращаться к ней)

Answer (score 0):

1) На кнопку вешайте слушатель нажатий.

2) В нём находите ListView

3) Делаете его невидимым. Например так:

```
listView.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста , а как сделать чтобы это действие повторялось ?

Comment: то есть чтобы можно было нажимать скрыть/показать много раз , и не прописывать в коде столько много условий

Comment: btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData_proversebya_animal);
                        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProversebyaAnimal.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output));
                        btn2.setText("Скрыть ошибки");

Comment: btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewData_proversebya_animal);
                                listview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ProversebyaAnimal.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, output));
                                btn2.setText("Показать ошибки");
                            }
                        });

Comment: @Дмитрий, код лучше в ответ пихать. По вопросу - проверяйте скрыт ли список. Например переменной по клику назначайте true/false и в обработчике нажатия её проверяйте и меняйте.

Comment: вот посмотрите код пожалуйста , как автоматизировать ? чтобы можно было много раз подряд нажимать скрыть/ показать

Comment: Ответ @DeKaNszn должен вас устроить.